# Code outputs all the powers of an integer upto 10,000

Tags: python, integer

So the exact question is: Write some code to print all of the powers of n less than 10,000, inclusive, assuming a variable n already
contains a positive integer. The output should show each number on a separate line, as below.
The output below assumes the following initialization for n:
n = 3
Sample Output for Part 2:
1
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561

The code I made is this:

```
n=input('What is the integer value of n? n= ')
while (int(n)<=10000):
    x=0
    n=(int(n))**(int(x))
    x += 1
    print(int(n))
```

However, when I run this code, it just prints 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 indefinitely, I thought that because I did the x += 1, the code would move to the next power, but it seems it is stuck at x=0. I am not sure how I can get this to work.

Comment: You're always resetting x to 0 at the top of your loop.  I think you want to set it to zero just once, outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you set x=0 inside your loop, this means that for any integer n you are putting it to the power of zero, which will always equal 1. 100**0 = 1 etc. This is why you are getting 1 as an answer each time

Take the initialized x=0 outside the loop, so it will start at zero and then increase by 1 for each iteration

```
x=0

n=input('What is the integer value of n? n= ')
while (int(n)<=10000):
    n=(int(n))**(int(x))
    x += 1
    print(int(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `while` condition to `pow(n, x) < 10000` then increase your `x` by 1 for every loop.

```
n = 3
x = 0
while pow(n, x) < 10000:
    print(pow(n, x))
    x += 1

'''
1
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561
'''
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I just changed n to being user inputted so it was                                
    n=input('What is the integer value of n? n= ')
    x = 0
    while pow(int(n), x) < 10000:
        print(pow(int(n), x))
        x += 1

Comment: @itiswhatitis of course, I figured you would convert that over to user input , just a demo, glad to help!

Comment: @itiswhatitis if this worked appreciate if you accepted answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You initialize x as 0 inside the loop,
But even if you didn't do it, you modify n before using the power operator (n**0=1 on first loop, then 1**1=1 on second loop, and so on)

This is how I would do it:

```
n=input('What is the integer value of n? n= ')
n = int(n)
x = 1
while x <= 10000:    
    print(x)
    x *= n
```

output:

```
1
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561
```